# Xcode cannot locate ruby script during run phase

Tags: ruby, xcode, scripting

command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby “${SRCROOT}/generate-games.rb” “${SRCROOT}/sample-data.csv”
```

```
error: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory --
“/Users/rays/Desktop/GenerateTestData/generate-games.rb” (LoadError)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit codet I
```

Yet I confirmed the script is where it should be.

Comment: Are you using literal `“”` marks in your path? Because those are not quotation marks (which look like `""`) and using them will generate this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are using UTF-8 quotes: `“...”` instead of standard ASCII quotes `"..."`. Your shell will will only recognize ASCII quotes as delimiters, and therefore will interpret the UTF-8 quotes as part of the file name (which they obviously are not).

**Conclusion**:
Fix your quotes and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved my problem.